# Photoshop Scripting (JSX): How to contract a layerSet?

Tags: photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

I searched everywhere by I'm unable to find the syntax/property to have a layerSet closed with a script.

I have this, my layerSet is expanded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuFw9.jpg

```
v Group 1
   - Layer 1
   - Layer 2
```

I'd like this, where my layerSet is closed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm6yE.jpg

```
> Group 1
```

At first, I was trying some things, as I know the layerSet name, but nothing ever happens.

```
doc.layerSets.getByName('Group 1').groupContract = true;
```

I tried with this other one, but it must not be the right one either.

```
doc.layerSets.getByName('Group 1').groupExpand = false;
```

If anyone has an idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer there, from JJMack:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1315645?start=0&tstart=0

It's a bit tricky, but it does the job.
Here's a simplified version:

```
//For code readability  
function cTID(s){return charIDToTypeID(s)}  
function sTID(s){return stringIDToTypeID(s)}  
// =============================        

function closeAllLayerSets(ref) {  
          var layers = ref.layers;  
          var len = layers.length;  
          for ( var i = 0; i < len; i ++) {  
                    var layer = layers[i];  
                    if (layer.typename == 'LayerSet') {app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer; closeGroup(layer); var layer = layers[i]; closeAllLayerSets(layer);};  
          }  
}  

function hasLayerMask() {  
   var m_Ref01 = new ActionReference();  
   m_Ref01.putEnumerated( sTID( "layer" ), cTID( "Ordn" ), cTID( "Trgt" ));  
   var m_Dsc01= executeActionGet( m_Ref01 );  
   return m_Dsc01.hasKey(cTID('Usrs'));  
}        

function addLayer() {  
   var m_ActiveLayer          =    activeDocument.activeLayer;  
   var m_NewLayer             =    activeDocument.artLayers.add();  
   m_NewLayer.move(m_ActiveLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);  

   return m_NewLayer;  
}  

function addToSelection(layerName) {  
   var m_Dsc01 = new ActionDescriptor();  
   var m_Ref01 = new ActionReference();  
   m_Ref01.putName( cTID( "Lyr " ), layerName );  
   m_Dsc01.putReference( cTID( "null" ), m_Ref01 );  
   m_Dsc01.putEnumerated( sTID( "selectionModifier" ), sTID( "selectionModifierType" ), sTID( "addToSelection" ) );  
   m_Dsc01.putBoolean( cTID( "MkVs" ), false );  

   try {  
      executeAction( cTID( "slct" ), m_Dsc01, DialogModes.NO );  
   } catch(e) {}  
}  

function groupSelected(name) {  
   var m_Dsc01 = new ActionDescriptor();  
   var m_Ref01 = new ActionReference();  
   m_Ref01.putClass( sTID( "layerSection" ) );  
   m_Dsc01.putReference(  cTID( "null" ), m_Ref01 );  
   var m_Ref02 = new ActionReference();  
   m_Ref02.putEnumerated( cTID( "Lyr " ), cTID( "Ordn" ), cTID( "Trgt" ) );  
   m_Dsc01.putReference( cTID( "From" ), m_Ref02 );  
   var m_Dsc02 = new ActionDescriptor();  
   m_Dsc02.putString( cTID( "Nm  " ), name);  
   m_Dsc01.putObject( cTID( "Usng" ), sTID( "layerSection" ), m_Dsc02 );  
   executeAction( cTID( "Mk  " ), m_Dsc01, DialogModes.NO );  

   return activeDocument.activeLayer;  
}      

function closeGroup(layerSet) {  
   var m_Name = layerSet.name;  
   var m_Opacity = layerSet.opacity;  
   var m_BlendMode = layerSet.blendMode;  
   var m_LinkedLayers = layerSet.linkedLayers;  

   var m_bHasMask = hasLayerMask();  
   if(m_bHasMask) loadSelectionOfMask();  


   if(layerSet.layers.length <= 1) {  
      addLayer();  
      var m_Tmp = activeDocument.activeLayer;  
      m_Tmp.name = "dummy - feel free to remove me";  
      activeDocument.activeLayer = layerSet;  
      ungroup();  
      addToSelection("dummy - feel free to remove me");  
      groupSelected(m_Name);  

   } else {  
      activeDocument.activeLayer = layerSet;  
      ungroup();  
      groupSelected(m_Name);  
   }  


   var m_Closed = activeDocument.activeLayer;  
   m_Closed.opacity = m_Opacity;  
   m_Closed.blendMode = m_BlendMode;  

   for(x in m_LinkedLayers) {  
      if(m_LinkedLayers[x].typename == "LayerSet")  
         activeDocument.activeLayer.link(m_LinkedLayers[x]);  
   }  

   if(m_bHasMask) maskFromSelection();  

   return m_Closed;  
}  

function ungroup() {  
   var m_Dsc01 = new ActionDescriptor();  
   var m_Ref01 = new ActionReference();  
   m_Ref01.putEnumerated( cTID( "Lyr " ), cTID( "Ordn" ), cTID( "Trgt" ) );  
   m_Dsc01.putReference( cTID( "null" ), m_Ref01 );  

   try {  
      executeAction( sTID( "ungroupLayersEvent" ), m_Dsc01, DialogModes.NO );  
   } catch(e) {}  
}  

closeAllLayerSets( app.activeDocument );
```